# Can we use Amazon RDS in Mule Standalone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster

We are planned to use `Amazon RDS`  and currently  using Mule Standalone.Can we use Amazon RDS in Mule and deploy in standalone. Reason I'm asking is there are few example over internet which is with CloudHub and Amazon RDS?. Hopefully shouldn't, but i'm confused.

Are we having any specific config difference in `Amazon RDS` with  `cloudhub` or using with `standalone`.

Any pros and cons using `Amazon RDS` with  cloudhub or with standalone.

Are we have specific connector for Amazon RDS  as like SQS?

Helpful on clarify the doubts.

If you have already used, Please let me know if anything which i need to keep me in mind on development.
Helpful if you direct me with url's also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I don't see any problem in using it. For the connector you just need to use the database connector with the right jdbc library depending on the database you choose to use on RDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference in using it with Cloudhub or Mule Standalone functionally. Just use the database connector and setup the correct JDBC properties: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/